# my header is not working in the php

Tags: php, html

When the submit button is pressed am not directed to the header even if condition with isset() is used.
Note:This is just a test page so i know storing password is not safe in way in which i have done

my index.php

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]==$_POST){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = "SELECT id FROM login WHERE username = '$username' AND password='$password'";
    $result= mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($count==1){
            header("location:welcome.php");
    }
    else{
        echo "invalid credentials";
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username"  placeholder = "Username"/>
<input  type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder = "**********"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

connect.php

```
<?php
   define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
   define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
   define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
   define('DB_DATABASE', 'users');
   $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
```

welcome.php

```
<?php

echo"Hello world";

?>
```

i havent used any sessions ignoring the fact is there anything i should change?

Comment: close your <head> tag before <body> tag.

Comment: Close head tag before open body tag. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server's REQUEST_METHOD is a string, you are comparing it to the _POST array.

Replace this

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]==$_POST){
```

with

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
```

to properly check the server's request method.
Then, the rest of your code should run.